# Magento Meta description showing "Items 1 - 44 of 781"

Tags: php, magento

When I check my category webpages on google for the meta description it shows my Items and the total amount of items then it shows my meta description after that. Here is an example

Momei Rugs - Quality Rugs - Area Rugs
www.website.com › Area Rug Brands & Manufacturers‎
Items 1 - 55 of 503 - Contemporary, Traditional, Hand Woven, Tufted, and more, Momeni is the brand of choice when it comes to combining quality, style, and color ...

I've been experiencing this issue on magento for quite some time now. Does anyone know how this can be fixed?

I am using magento 1.8.1.0 on the modern theme.

Comment: Can you please state the problem clearly? What is the expected behavior? I don't think that is a meta-description, I think google is pulling text right from your website.

Comment: You might have more luck over on the Magento StackExchange — Stack Overflow is for programming questions, and while you problem might have a programming solution, the way you've phrased it doesn't. http://magento.stackexchange.com

Comment: Sorry about that. Yes Google is pulling this text from the website and I would like to know how to correct this issue. Please see this webpage as an example http://www.ruglots.com/rug-brands/momeni-area-rugs.html

Comment: Attach a screenshot of how u are experiencing it in google or any other and also what is your desired output.. We will try to help u with that..

Comment: Sure, please see this link. http://bit.ly/1oAtCNN 

My desired output is not to have the Items text (section in the red box)

Comment: No one knows how to do this?